# Initialisting KeyInfo with X509 certificate parameters

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, x509certificate

This is a question for C# language.

I am having a reference to X509 Certificate in one class A(**call it sslCert**) i.e i can access the various members associated with the X509 certificate.

Also, i am having a Class B having following 2 crypto key members -->
**KeyInfo publicKey;
KeyInfo privateKey;**

The problem is that i am not able to find the way to set these 2 values (publickey & privatekey) with the Public Key and Private Key values from the X509. Direct assignment doesnt work and complains about data type mismatches.

```
B.publicKey = A.sslcertificate.Certificate.PublicKey;
B.privateKey = A.sslcertificate.Certificate.PrivateKey;
```

I have tried alot but not knowing what is the exact assignment way to achieve that. Anyone can throw some light on this?

Thanks !!!

Comment: It would be nice of you to add some code or clarify that exactly you trying to accomplish. It looks like you trying to set values of your class using values from x509 which sounds weird for me, so please provide more information.

Comment: Added the code. Class B has publicKey and privateKey members which are of type KeyInfo. A.sslcertificate.Certificate gives us the X509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you trying to do? I'm sorry, still trying to get the idea.

```
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        public class A
        {
            private string website = "https://www.chase.com/";
            private X509Certificate m_certificate;

            public X509Certificate Certificate
            {
                get
                {
                    if (m_certificate == null)
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(website);
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                        response.Close();
                        X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
                        m_certificate = cert;
                    }
                    return m_certificate;
                }
            }
            public X509Certificate2 Certificate2
            {
                get
                {
                    return new X509Certificate2(Certificate);
                }
            }
        }

        public class B
        {
            public KeyInfo publicKey { get; set; }
            public KeyInfo privateKey { get; set; }
        }

        class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                A tempA = new A();
                B tempB = new B();

                tempB.privateKey = tempA.Certificate.GetPublicKey(); // fails
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am doing something similar. The below line in above code fails.  tempB.privateKey = tempA.Certificate.GetPublicKey(); // fails         Also, i dont know how to set the Private key field of class A using Private key of Class B X509 certificate as there is no direct assignable GetPrivateKey method. In my Visual Studio 10 IDE, i dont get KeyInfoX509Data as the recognized data type. Please suggest.

Comment: Okay, so I'm referencing 3 libraries System, System.Security, System.Xml and you can see this code above and that's pretty match it. You can download sources here http://zalil.ru/34133542 it will be available till 13.01.2013 I hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the cert:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate;
```

you just

```
KeyInfo ki = new KeyInfo();
KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data( certificate );
ki.AddClause( keyInfoData );
```

This stores the whole certificate in the key info. Both private and public part can be stored separately, you just have to initialize the KeyInfo with other types of clauses. Complete list of supported clauses:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.keyinfoclause.aspx

Comment: In my Visual Studio 10 IDE, i dont get KeyInfoX509Data as the recognized data type. It shows error and not able to use that.

Comment: Too bad you didn't try to google that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.keyinfox509data.aspx

Comment: seems you still don't understand what i pointed out. even after importing/using the necessary package the KeyInfoX509Data is not getting used.

Comment: This would only be possible in case of a console application targeting the Client Framework, possibly. If this is so, retarget your project to full Framework. In any other case the class just HAS TO BE available, it is a part of the net framework, there is no reason for why it should not be available.